Битрикс, как получить ID товара по свойству?
Хочу получить ID товара по определенному свойству.
Кусок кода:
$propertyValue = "123456789";
$sectionId = 185;
$iblockId = 38;
$propertyCode = "P_ARTICLE";

// Формирование фильтра
$arFilter = array(
    "IBLOCK_ID" => $iblockId,
    "SECTION_ID" => $sectionId, // фильтр по разделу
    "=PROPERTY_".$propertyCode => $propertyValue
);

// Выборка нужных полей
$arSelect = array("ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_".$propertyCode);

$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array("SORT"=>"ASC"), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
if ($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    // информации о товаре
    echo "ID: " . $arFields["ID"] . "<br>";
    echo "Название: " . $arFields["NAME"] . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Товар не найден";
}

Но выводит последний товар а не то что указано в свойстве. Значение свойства соответственно уникальное.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я пропустил?

Отвечаю сам.
В $propertyCode должно быть ID свойства.
